# AWS EC2 - Give folder permission to uploaded files using html form

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, file-permissions, user-permissions

I am trying to upload a file to AWS EC2 using HTML form. I am creating a folder dynamically and inside which I am uploading the file. But the problem is the folder which gets created has 755 permission and I think because of which my file is not getting uploaded to that folder.

> mkdir($target, 0777) doesn't make the folder 777.
>
> print_r($_FILES) is giving good results yet the file is not getting
>   uploaded.

The folder which gets created is having user as "apache" and group as "www".

My question is: how can I change the dynamically created folder permission from 755 to 775 which I am unable to do no-matter what?

Please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Default folder permissions are controlled by umask for the user creating the folder.

You need to change the umask for the apache user:

```
sudo su - apache

chmod g+s /path/to/folder
setfacl -d -m g::rwx /path/to/folder
setfacl -d -m o::rx /path/to/folder
```

Then verify with

```
getfacl /path/to/folder
```

Now when your code creates a /path/to/folder/sub-folder, it should have 775 permissions

Comment: Thanks for writing and sorry for replying late. Now, my code is creating folder with 775 permission but file is not getting uploaded. Any reason?

Comment: Need more info, are you using an application container (like tomcat) with an application to process the form submits? If so then do you see anything in the tomcat error log? Maybe post some code, might help.

Comment: Hey, I dont know how come my message got deleted. I have already solved the problem. Thanks.